# my soap server module does not receive Client form

Tags: java, xml, web, soap, service

I have developed a soap server but now i had one problem , problem in `SOAP ENV` and `SOAP BODY`. My client request form is without `soapenv` and `soapbody`
only have a values.

after executing my module export message is

> 'Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element
>   is not named Envelope'

but client form could not change.

client form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns1:inputSOATest xmlns:ns1="http://javainuse.com">
    <ns1:requestSet>
    <ns2:userInfo xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2018/08/SscntBigdata.userInfo">
    <ns2:EMPID></ns2:EMPID>
    <ns2:SINGLEID/>
    <ns2:EPID/>
    <ns2:NAME></ns2:NAME>
    <ns2:ENGNAME></ns2:ENGNAME>
    <ns2:EMPTYPE>PAA</ns2:EMPTYPE>
    <ns2:LVABSENCE/>
    <ns2:RETIRE/>
    <ns2:EMAIL/>
    <ns2:TELNUM/>
    <ns2:MBPHONE/>
    <ns2:BSCADDR></ns2:BSCADDR>
    <ns2:ZZBUKRS>J604</ns2:ZZBUKRS>

    <ns2:DEPTNM>
    <ns2:DEPTNM> China RMD BPL Part</ns2:DEPTNM>
    <ns2:SPRAS>1</ns2:SPRAS>
    </ns2:DEPTNM>

    <ns2:DEPTNM>
    <ns2:DEPTNM> BPL Part</ns2:DEPTNM>
    <ns2:SPRAS>3</ns2:SPRAS>
    </ns2:DEPTNM>

    <ns2:PDEPTNM>
    <ns2:PDEPTNM></ns2:PDEPTNM>
    <ns2:SPRAS>3</ns2:SPRAS>
    </ns2:PDEPTNM>

    <ns2:PDEPTNM>
    <ns2:PDEPTNM></ns2:PDEPTNM>
    <ns2:SPRAS>E</ns2:SPRAS>
    </ns2:PDEPTNM>

    <ns2:CORPNM>
    <ns2:CORPNM>ion Trading</ns2:CORPNM>
    <ns2:SPRAS>E</ns2:SPRAS>
    </ns2:CORPNM>

    <ns2:CORPNM>
    <ns2:CORPNM>Trading</ns2:CORPNM>
    <ns2:SPRAS>3</ns2:SPRAS>
    </ns2:CORPNM>

    <ns2:JOBNM>
    <ns2:JOBNM></ns2:JOBNM>
    <ns2:SPRAS>3</ns2:SPRAS>
    </ns2:JOBNM>


    <ns2:JOBGRDNM>
    <ns2:JOBGRDNM>()</ns2:JOBGRDNM>
    <ns2:SPRAS>3</ns2:SPRAS>
    </ns2:JOBGRDNM>

    <ns2:JOBGRDNM>
    <ns2:JOBGRDNM></ns2:JOBGRDNM>
    <ns2:SPRAS>1</ns2:SPRAS>
    </ns2:JOBGRDNM>
    </ns2:userInfo>
    </ns1:requestSet></ns1:inputSOATest>
```

how do i can that?

Answer (score 0):

SOAP msgs are always in SOAP-ENV, SOAP-HEADER and SOAP-BODY format. 
I can see your request has inputSOATest tag. If I am understanding currectly. Client data is from SOA. I thnk you have to convert SOA test to proper SOAP msg before sending to server.